# Why is this C++ code producing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

The code function that I'm specifically talking about is getCount(). There are several other functions that I haven't included here (such as finding the height of this binary tree and the total node count) which work just fine, with correct results. getCount() on the other hand produces segmentation fault except for the first node (the top, first node of the tree). Any ideas?

```
#include <string> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Word {
    public:
        std::string keyval;
        long long count;
        Word() {
            keyval = "";
            count = 0;
        }
        Word(std::string S) {
            keyval = S;
            count = 1;
        }
};

class WordBST {
    public:
        Word node;
        WordBST* left_child;
        WordBST* right_child;
        WordBST(std::string key);        
        void add(std::string key){
            if (key == node.keyval){
                node.count++;
            }
            else if (key < node.keyval){
                if (left_child == NULL){
                    left_child = new WordBST(key);
                }else {
                    left_child->add(key);
                }
            }else {
                if (right_child == NULL){
                    right_child = new WordBST(key);
                }else {
                    right_child->add(key);
                }
            }
        }
        long long getCount(std::string key){
            if (key == node.keyval){
                return (node.count);
            }
            else if (key < node.keyval){
                left_child->getCount(key);
            }else if(key > node.keyval){
                right_child->getCount(key);
            }else return 0;
            /*else {
                if (key < node.keyval){
                    left_child->getCount(key);
                }else{
                    right_child->getCount(key);
                }
            }*/
        }
};

WordBST::WordBST(std::string key) {
    node = Word(key);
    left_child = NULL;
    right_child = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Are `left_child` and `right_child` valid pointers when you dereference them the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you let your code run off the end without hitting a return statement.

```
long long getCount(std::string key){
    if (key == node.keyval){
        return (node.count);
    } else if (left_child && key < node.keyval){
        return left_child->getCount(key); // Added return
    } else if(right_child && key > node.keyval){
        return right_child->getCount(key); // Added return
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You also need to add null checks in more than one place throughout the code. Your `add` method has them, but your `getCount` does not.

Comment: What does `getCount` not returning a value have to do with segmentation faults?

Comment: @Aesthete According to C++ spec, not returning a value from a function that is declared as returning a value is undefined behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Short and sweet solution. This worked fantastically. Thank you. I'm wondering though, what was actually happening without the return statement? Oh and yes, you're right I'll implement the null checks right now.

Comment: @Aesthete add() function is void, so no return needed there. getCount() on the other hand must return a long long. I should have noticed that right away. EDIT: I see dasblinkenlight answered it before I did.

Comment: @Nico - I realise that a function declared with a return type _should_ return a value, I'm just not convinced that it will cause segmentation fault. But as **dasblinkenlight** mentioned, undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NicoBellic To be honest, I can only guess why forgetting to return a value causes a segfault: my only guess would be that `long long` is returned through the stack, rather than through a register, because it does not fit. It may be an interesting experiment to switch the return type to `int`, drop the `return` again, and see if you get a crash or just a wrong value.

Comment: @Aesthete apparently it does. Segmentation fault went away as soon as I added return.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Alright, just did. No segmentation fault for int, but I do get the wrong answer. Huh, this is interesting.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Switched back, but now I'm receiving a segmentation fault for when the node doesn't exist.

Comment: Well on my compiler it returns `-858993460` in debug, and `20` in release, which interestingly enough happenens after the end of a for loop (1-20), and is the value still in the `eax` register.

Comment: You should be checking your left and right nodes before dereferencing them, see @laifjei answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write getCount() like this:

```
    long long getCount(std::string key){
    if (key == node.keyval){
        return (node.count);
    }
    else if (key < node.keyval && left_child != NULL){
        return left_child->getCount(key);
    }else if(key > node.keyval && right_child != NULL){
        return right_child->getCount(key);
    }else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not check to see if the children of your node exist before calling their methods.